# eliminate NAs from a database imported from EXCEL

Tags: database, excel

I imported this database from EXCEL:

[Excel file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d5c8pt8lg30v45u/PESI%20231117.xlsx?dl=0)

By default, empty spaces in RIPRO column are identified as NAs, so when I try to eliminate these and turn them to empty spaces or whatever using this code:

```
pesi<-PESI_231117
is.na(pesi$RIPRO)<-""
```

That's what I get always. I think I tried almost everything to fix that, with no success:

[image]

Can you help me? Many thanks in advance and kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's the same file with spaces instead of blanks](http://jmp.sh/s36koSk)...  :-)

What language are you using to import?  Is that *R*?

Obviously my answer isn't a coding solution, but often the simplest solutions are the best.  If this is a one-time file import then coding isn't necessarily the best solution.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, but I am sorry; I am not sure to understand you. How did you get it? handling the source excel file? What I pretended is to find a way in rstudio to eliminate NAs once imported the source file. Thanks.

Comment: thanks, most probably you are true; and how do you handle the source file to that other one in excel?

Comment: I opened it in Excel and hit: CTRL+H, delete, tab, delete, space, `Replace All` ..  I know that's not the solution you're looking for but I thought I'd throw it out there since it literally took <10 seconds.